# Telerik Report Viewer messed up

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, telerik, telerik-reporting

Telerik Report messed up like [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/report-viewers/the-styles-of-the-web-report-viewer-s-toolbar-are-messed-up.aspx)

Tried this fix that the article suggests but in vain..ie added "preCondition" attribute but we.config says preCondition="integratedMode" Attribute is not declared"..Where do I need to declare it and how!??

I added xmlns value like this in web.config after reading a forum:-

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

It still is giving this error:-

Unrecognized attribute 'preCondition'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

**[EDIT]
ok that fix is for IIS7..didn't notice..mine is IIS 5..so how do I fix the appearance of Telerik Report Viewer now??**

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, verify that you have the right "Version=xxxxx" on the web.config reference to the Telerik.ReportViewer.axd.
I've seen sometimes the report viewer messed up becasue the web.config was referencing an older version.

sample:

```
....
....
<add name="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd_*" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=5.1.11.928, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
</handlers>
...
...
  <add verb="*" path="Telerik.ReportViewer.axd" type="Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.HttpHandler, Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=5.1.11.928, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" validate="true" />
</httpHandlers>
```